# Are there other, non-probabilistic ways to calculate: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln\sum_{m>n\alpha}\frac{(n\lambda)^m}{m!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In section five of [this nice exposition](https://researchers.ms.unimelb.edu.au/%7Exgge%40unimelb/Files/Teaching/Advanced%20Probability%20(Semester%201%202020)/The%20Theory%20of%20Moment%20Generating%20Functions.pdf) of moment generating functions, we prove the following theorem:

> Take an i.i.d sequence of random variables $(X_n:\Omega\to\Bbb R)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ whose common cumulant generating function $\Lambda$ is finite in a neighbourhood of the origin (the value $+\infty$ is permitted in general). Let $X:=X_1$.
>
> Define $\Lambda^\ast$ to be the "Fenchel-Legendre transform" of $\Lambda$: $$\Lambda^\ast:\Bbb R\to\overline{\Bbb R},\,x\mapsto\sup_{t\in\Bbb R}(x\cdot t-\Lambda(t))$$And define for every $n\in\Bbb N$ the empirical means: $$Y_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j:\Omega\to\Bbb R$$
>
> If $\alpha>\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Pr}(X>\alpha)>0$ then $0<\Lambda^\ast(\alpha)<\infty$ and we get the asymptotics of the "large deviations": $$\frac{1}{n}\ln\mathrm{Pr}(Y_n>\alpha)\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}-\Lambda^\ast(\alpha)=\inf_{t>0}(\Lambda(t)-\alpha\cdot t)$$With convergence from below.

The proof is - to me - a fairly complex and delicate application of probability theory. I don't yet know enough to follow it all the way through. I wanted to "see it in action" so I explicitly calculated $\Lambda^\ast$ for the Poisson distribution.

Let's fix some $\lambda>0$. If we take $(X_n)_n$ which follow the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, it is easy to check that $\Lambda(t)=\lambda(e^t-1)$ for all $t$. Some basic calculus optimisation will find: $$\Lambda^\ast(\alpha)=\lambda+\alpha(\ln(\alpha\cdot\lambda^{-1})-1)$$Whenever $\alpha>\lambda$.

So the theorem predicts that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\sum_{m>n\alpha}\frac{(n\lambda)^m}{m!}e^{-n\lambda}\right)=-\lambda+\alpha(1-\ln(\alpha\cdot\lambda^{-1}))$$A little rearranging brings that to: $$\tag{$\ast$}\forall\,\,0<\lambda<\alpha:\quad\quad\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\sum_{m>n\alpha}\frac{(n\lambda)^m}{m!}\right)=\alpha(1-\ln(\alpha\cdot\lambda^{-1}))$$

Which seems highly nontrivial to do by other means. I am very curious to see whether or not anyone on the site has the expertise to supply a "real analytic" proof of this identity. I know that the probabilistic proof is just a real analytic proof with a particular flavour, but I mean to ask if there are other ways of doing this which aren't purely motivated by ideas from probability or measure theory (the proof seems to involve a "change-of-measure" trick, which is a new one on me). Or, if this special Poisson case admits a simpler probabilistic proof, that would be interesting to see too.

I think this special case is an interesting problem. Since I don't fully understand the proof I've already seen, I reckon that verifying $(\ast)$ is way above my paygrade. I hope to learn from your answers :)

Just one thing I can helpfully observe:

> By the Stolz-Cesaro theorem, it would suffice to show that (although I do not know if this is true): $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{m>(n+1)\alpha}\frac{((n+1)\lambda)^m}{m!}}{\sum_{m>n\alpha}\frac{(n\lambda)^m}{m!}}=\left(\frac{\lambda e}{\alpha}\right)^\alpha$$

---

Oh, and a related cool (I think) expression can be deduced by applying the same technique to a sequence of binomial variable variables with parameters $n,1/2$:

> If $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\frac{n}{2}<\alpha<n$ then: $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m}\ln\left(\sum_{k>m\alpha}\binom{mn}{k}\right)=n\ln n-\alpha\ln\alpha-(n-\alpha)\ln(n-\alpha)$$
>
> More generally, if $0<p<1$, $n\in\Bbb N$ and $np<\alpha<n$: $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m}\ln\left(\sum_{k>m\alpha}\binom{mn}{k}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k\right)=\alpha\ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)+n\ln n-\alpha\ln\alpha-(n-\alpha)\ln(n-\alpha)$$

This also seems quite nontrivial without this “master theorem”. I would be equally interested to see a proof of that by other means.

Comment: Did you try writing the integral formula for the error term in the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ of degree $m \approx n\alpha $  and setting $x=n \lambda$? Perhaps that bound might suffice.

Comment: @MathWonk No I haven’t tried this. I’ll think on it. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $0<\lambda<\alpha$. By [$(8.4.9)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E9) and [$(8.6.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6.E3), we have
$$\tag{1}
\hspace{-20pt}\sum\limits_{m > n\alpha } {\frac{{(n\lambda )^m }}{{m!}}}  = {\rm e}^{n\lambda } P(n\alpha  + 1,n\lambda ) = \frac{{(n\lambda )^{n\alpha  + 1} {\rm e}^{n\lambda } }}{{\Gamma (n\alpha  + 1)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - n(\alpha t + \lambda {\rm e}^{ - t} )){\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t} .
$$
The saddle point $t = \log (\lambda /\alpha ) < 0$ is outside the range of integration and the minimum of $t\mapsto \alpha t + \lambda {\rm e}^{ - t} $ occurs at $t=0$. Whence, by [Laplace's method](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3#iii),
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - n(\alpha t + \lambda {\rm e}^{ - t} )){\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t}  \sim \frac{1}{{\alpha  - \lambda }}\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - n\lambda } }}{n}
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. Hence by $(1)$ and Stirling's formula,
$$
\sum\limits_{m > n\alpha } {\frac{{(n\lambda )^m }}{{m!}}}  \sim \frac{\lambda }{{\alpha  - \lambda }}\sqrt {\frac{{2\pi n}}{\alpha }} \left( {\frac{{\lambda {\rm e}}}{\alpha }} \right)^{n\alpha } 
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. Finally,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\log \!\bigg( {\sum\limits_{m > n\alpha } {\frac{{(n\lambda )^m }}{{m!}}} } \bigg) \sim \alpha \log\! \bigg( {\frac{{\lambda {\rm e}}}{\alpha }} \bigg) = \alpha (1 - \log (\alpha /\lambda ))
$$
as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: Very clean. One thing: I don’t think I saw it there - what are $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: If you click on the link it will define all the notation appearing in the formula. The $P(a,z)$ is the normalised incomplete gamma function: $\gamma(a,z)/\Gamma(a)$. DLMF is a useful website with lots of information.

Comment: Ah I clicked on it but somehow missed the definition.

Comment: So I am aware of a rigorous approach to Laplace’s method for the formulation where there is one and only one saddle point in the interior of the domain of integration. Do you happen to know a reference for a rigorous approach to the formulation given by DLMF?

Comment: Click on the $i$ icon on the right-hand side of the section title $\S2.3(\text{iii})$ and it will tell you with a link to the reference: "See Olver (1997b, pp. 80–88)."

Comment: That is interesting, because the asymptotic nature of the integral should not change. If there is a saddle point that contributes, the behaviour is of order $\mathrm{e}^{-n\lambda}/\sqrt{n}$ and not $\mathrm{e}^{-n\lambda}/n$. Did you change the integration interval correctly? It becomes $(1,\infty)$ and the saddle will still be outside.

Comment: I used $s=e^{-t}$ with interval $(0,1)$ but I now realise the new saddle point at $\alpha/\lambda$ is not actually inside the bounds of integration as I’ve assumed $\alpha>\lambda$